# confused about the proof of a valid argument

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

This is from notes:

[image]

I don't understand why $p\wedge s$ needs to be true, even $p\wedge s$ is false and $t$ is true, then $p\wedge s\rightarrow t$ is still true.

Comment: You are right ! The argument is not "semantical" but "syntactical". In order to **derive** $t$, the only way is to "detach" it by *modus ponens* from $(p \land s) \to t$, that means that we have to derive in some way $p \land s$. To do this, we have to derive separately $p$ and $s$ and then use $\land$-intro to "conjoin" them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, the solution given is trying to explain the way to **obtain** the proof, and is not itself the proof! The point is that only one of the given assumptions mentions $t$, so without that assumption you can't prove anything about $t$. Hence you know you must use that assumption, but it is of the form $A \to t$, and the only way to use it to prove $t$ is to prove $A$ first and use modus ponens. So we try to prove $A$, which happens to be of the form $B \land C$. Similarly here it's not possible to prove the conjunction without being able to prove the individual conjuncts separately, so we attempt to do that... And so on.

Comment: So yes you're right that if $p \land s$ is false then $( p \land s \to t )$ would be true, but it's just that the author didn't make it very clear that he/she is showing how to construct the proof by backward reasoning. Such reasoning may fail and lead to nonsense if there is actually no proof!